# How can I show console.log in nightwatch.js?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

Currently trying to show the console.logs. This is my output:

```
 'server', 'browser', 'driver' ]
 √ Element <body> was visible after 115 milliseconds.
[ { level: 'SEVERE',
...
```

My test looks like this:

```
var config = require('../conf.js');

module.exports = {
    'e2e test': function(browser) {
        browser
            .url('http://localhost:3000/')
            .getLogTypes(function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            })

            .waitForElementVisible('body')
            .useXpath()
            .click('/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]')
            .pause(5000)
            .click('/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/section[2]/div/article/header/a')
            .pause(5000)
            .getLog('browser', function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            })
            .end();
    }
};
```

How can I return the console.log output in my test?

Answer (score 2):

`.getLog('browser', function(logEntriesArray) {})` will return an array with the current messages in the browser's console.

To get all the console messages you can do something in the lines of:

```
  .getLog('browser', function(logEntriesArray) {
    if (logEntriesArray.length) {
      console.log('Log length: ' + logEntriesArray.length);
      logEntriesArray.forEach(function(log) {
        console.log(
          '[' + log.level + '] ' + log.timestamp + ' : ' + log.message
        );
      });
    }
  });
```